# Need to migrate the whole cluster from one DC to another DC

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I have a SolrCloud cluster consists of 5 hosts in one DC.
The collection configuration is 5 shards and 3 replicas and max 3 shards per host.

Solr version used is 5.3.1.

Because of some unforeseen maintenance activity, it needs to be moved to some other DC temporarily. In order to minimize the impact we need the indexed data to be available with the new setup. All the nodes has roughly 100GB of indexed data.

I already have tried copying the whole setup to the new DC and restarted after after updating the host information in the config files. It always complains some or other shards not available from hosts while querying data. [error code 503]

Note: The back up was taken from a running setup.

I also have tried creating the whole cluster again with the same configuration and copying only the data directory from the back up. It also results in `shards not available` from the hosts.

I wanted to understand if there is something wrong in the process I am following. One thing I am suspecting is , the back up should be taken after stoping a particular node.

Is there any simple and better way available? I am using Solr-5.3.1.

Answer (score 0):

The right way to do it is using [backup and restore](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/making-and-restoring-backups.html) feature. This feature was already available in the 5.3 version, check the appropiate doc and follow the steps. Should work just fine.